# Array sum of selected dates from the array of rooms with set dates and prices

Tags: php

I've got an array of selected dates and an array of rooms with set dates and prices. From the array `$selectedDates`, it should look for a date from the rooms. If one of the `$selectedDates` is found from each room, it should use the price under the `options` keys if not it should use the `default_price` key.

```
$selectedDates = ['10-04-2022', '11-04-2022', '12-04-2022'];

$setRooms = [
  0 => [
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Room1',
    'default_price' => 50,
    'options' => [
      0 => [
        'date' => '12-04-2022',
        'price' => 100,
      ],
      1 => [
        'date' => '13-04-2022',
        'price' => 200,
      ],
      3 => [
        'date' => '14-04-2022',
        'price' => 200,
      ],
    ]
  ],
 1 => [
    'id' => 2,
    'title' => 'Room2',
    'default_price' => 120,
    'options' => [
      0 => [
        'date' => '11-04-2022',
        'price' => 200,
      ],
      1 => [
        'date' => '12-04-2022',
        'price' => 300,
      ],
      3 => [
        'date' => '13-04-2022',
        'price' => 400,
      ],
    ]
  ],
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  // '10-04-2022' = 50 (default_price), '11-04-2022' = 50 (default_price), '12-04-2022' = 100 (using the option price). 50 + 50 + 100 = 200
  0 => [
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Room1',
    'total_price' => 200 
  ],
   // '10-04-2022' = 50 (default_price), '11-04-2022' = 200 (using the option price), '12-04-2022' = 300 (using the option price). 120 + 200 + 300 = 620
  1 => [
    'id' => 2,
    'title' => 'Room2',
    'total_price' => 620
  ]
]
```

This is what I've done so far. But it turns out that room 2 is giving me a different output, it's like the sum of room 1 will be added to room 2.

```
$price = 0;
$roomBookings = [];
foreach ($hotelRooms as $key => $room) {

    $count = count($listOfSelectedDates);
    foreach ($listOfSelectedDates as $selectedDate) {

        $getPrice = HelperTrait::searchForDate($selectedDate, $room['options']);
        if ($getPrice['success']) {
            $price += $getPrice['price'];
        }
        else {
            $price += $room['default_price'];
        }
        $room['total_price'] = $price;
    }
    $roomBookings[] = $room;
}

/////
public static function searchForDate($date, $array): array
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $date = Carbon::parse($date)->format('d-m-Y');
        $arrDate = Carbon::parse($val['date'])->format('d-m-Y');

        if ($arrDate === $date) {
            return [
                'success' => true,
                'price' => $val['price']
           ];
        }
    }

    return [
        'success' => false
    ];
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your description and your expected output do not match. For Room1 it would be 100 for '12-04-2022' and not 200. For Room2 it would be 500 for '11-04-2022' + '12-04-2022' and not 550. Or do I understand that wrongly?

Comment: I have to update the description to make it more clear. It should be 200 since 100 for '12-04-2022' then the date '10-04-2022', '11-04-2022' will be using the default price which is 50. Did you get what I mean? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think it should be 620 for Room2: '10-04-2022' -> 120, '11-04-2022' –> 200, '12-04-2022' –> 300

Comment: @lukas.j oh yes you're right! thanks that's a good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$setRooms = [
    [
        'id'            => 1,
        'title'         => 'Room1',
        'default_price' => 50,
        'options'       => [
            [ 'date' => '12-04-2022', 'price' => 100, ],
            [ 'date' => '13-04-2022', 'price' => 200, ],
            [ 'date' => '14-04-2022', 'price' => 200, ],
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id'            => 2,
        'title'         => 'Room2',
        'default_price' => 120,
        'options'       => [
            [ 'date' => '11-04-2022', 'price' => 200, ],
            [ 'date' => '12-04-2022', 'price' => 300, ],
            [ 'date' => '13-04-2022', 'price' => 400, ],
        ]
    ],
];

$selectedDates = [ '10-04-2022', '11-04-2022', '12-04-2022' ];

$result = [];

foreach ($setRooms as $room) {
  $total = 0;
  foreach ($selectedDates as $date) {
    $filtered = array_filter($room['options'], fn($option) => $date === $option['date']);
    if (count($filtered) === 1) {
      $total += $filtered[array_key_first($filtered)]['price'];
    } else {
      $total += $room['default_price'];
    }
  }
  $result[] = [ 'id' => $room['id'], 'title' => $room['title'], 'total_price' => $total ];
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Room1
            [total_price] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Room2
            [total_price] => 620
        )

)
```

Comment: gonna have a look will be back in a few minutes thanks

Comment: it works man, thanks a lot!